# change text written in english into hindi

Tags: comments, search

i want to change the text written in english into hindi inside my search bar, i am developing a hindi newspaper website by using wordpress cms so when user type in english to search related news in search bar that text should change in hindi because all the news in written in hindi so searching news become easy.please help me if somebody know. here is my wordpress by default search code:

```
<section class="search_main">
       <div class="search_box">
           <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">  
              <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar eng my_control" name="s" id="search" placeholder="search....." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn my-btn"  id="searchsubmit"  type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                      </span>
              </div><!--input group-->

              </form> 
       </div><!--search box-->

       </section><!--search main-->
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? They enter an English word which is automatically translated to Hindi. Then the search is performed using this Hindi word? Correct?

Comment: yes exactly that what i mean

Comment: You'd have to intercept the search queries and replace the search term, but the actual translation is offtopic. I would advise against it simply because it will either involve a costly translation software setup, or a query to a remote service, slowing your search down quite badly. Also if it gets it wrong or mistranslates then it will not be making life easier for your user. Also if the user is searching an all hindi website, can they not type a hindi search term?

Comment: thanks for support Tom, by default search is performed in hindi thats why i need to translate word in hindi that typed in english, i only need translator do you know translator api of google i think that work for me but i dont know how embed that with my code

Comment: The english -> hindi translation API part is off topic, and should be a separate question, probably on stackoverflow